# C++ Caesar cipher - follow-up

Tags: c++, caesar-cipher

I asked [another question the other day](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/214879/implementation-ceaser-cipher-in-c) and decided to rewrite the code with some of the suggestions given and add functionality (instead of reading from a console I'm reading directly from a file) the code works.

Looking at it, I think the nested `for` loop on the encode function doesn't look that good. I tried using `std::transform` like the comment on the code. It worked when I used the console just to read a line, now with vectors couldn't make it work.

```
// Ceaser Cipher implementation

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>


std::vector<std::string> encode(const std::vector<std::string> &str, int shift)
{
    std::vector<std::string> tempMsg;

    for (std::string lines : str)
    {
        // std::transform(lines.cbegin(), lines.cend(), std::back_inserter(tempMsg), [&](char ch) -> char
        for (char &ch : lines)
        {
            if (ch == 'z' || ch == 'Z')
            {
                ch -= 25;
            }
            else if (isspace(ch)) {
                ch = ' ';
            }
            else
            {
                ch += shift;
            }
        }
        tempMsg.push_back(lines);
    }

    return tempMsg;
}

std::vector<std::string> decode(const std::vector<std::string> &str, int shift)
{
    return encode(str, -1 * shift);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int choice;
    std::cout << "What do you want to do? 1.Encrypt, 2.Decrypt: ";
    std::cin >> choice;


    int key;
    std::cout << "Enter desired shift: ";
    std::cin >> key;


    std::ifstream inFile("testfile.txt");
    if (!(inFile.is_open()))
    {
        std::cout << "There was a problem with the file!";
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // ExitProcess() if windows especific.
    }

    std::vector<std::string> finalResult;

    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;


    while (std::getline(inFile, line))
    {
        lines.push_back(line);
    }
    inFile.close();

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        auto result = encode(lines, key);
        finalResult = result;
    }

    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        auto result = decode(lines, key);
        finalResult = result;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Wrong option, exiting!";
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    std::ofstream outFile("testfile.txt");
    for (auto i = finalResult.begin(); i != finalResult.end(); ++i)
    {
        outFile << *i << '\n';
    }
    outFile.close();

    std::exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include your test cases. The test cases should contain at least one test that shifts the complete alphabet by 7 places and unshifts it again. Another test should demonstrate what happens when you encode a phone number by shifting it 32 places and then decode it again. (I expect these tests to fix the worst bugs.) As long as there are no answers yet, you may still update the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following, I am omitting checking for the correctness of the outputs as you have not provided a specification for what that should be. Nevertheless, consider the following points.

- I think the signatures of your encoding and decoding functions are a bit unexpected: I would expect an encoding function to take a single string and not a vector of strings. This gives me the feeling that the function is doing too much (i.e., violating the guideline of *one function, one responsibility*). So I would break the logic into smaller pieces:

  ```
  std::string encode(const std::string& str, int shift)
  {
      std::string str_enc;
      std::transform(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), std::back_inserter(str_enc), [&](char ch) -> char 
      { 
          if (ch == 'z' || ch == 'Z')
          {
              return ch - 25;
          }
          else if (isspace(ch)) 
          {
              return ' ';
          }
          else
          {
              return ch + shift;
          }
      });

      return str_enc;
  }

  std::vector<std::string> encode(const std::vector<std::string>& str, int shift)
  {
      std::vector<std::string> tempMsg;
      std::transform(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), std::back_inserter(tempMsg),
          [&](const std::string& s) { return encode(s, shift); });

      return tempMsg;
  }
  ```
- In the main loop logic, before getting into any file reading, check whether the `choice` made by the user is sensible (either 1 or 2). This allows you to make `finalResult` const and to initialize it in a nicer way. This is a good modern practice as given by e.g., [ES.28 of the C++ Core Guidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-lambda-init):

  ```
  assert(choice == 1 || choice == 2);
  const std::vector<std::string> finalResult = [&]()
  {
      return choice == 1 ? encode(lines, key) : decode(lines, key);
  }();
  ```
- You don't have to explicitly close file streams. They close upon destruction.
- To check if the file is good to go, you can do `if(inFile) { ... }` invoking its `operator bool()` which tells you if the stream has no errors and is ready for I/O operations (specifically, it returns `!fail()`).
- When writing to file, you can use standard algorithms (like `std::copy`) since your logic is very simple:

  ```
  std::ofstream outFile("outfile.txt");
  std::copy(finalResult.cbegin(), finalResult.cend(), 
      std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(outFile, "\n"));
  ```
- Everywhere in your code, avoid using `std::exit` (for reasons and more discussion, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38724788/what-is-the-difference-between-exit-and-stdexit-in-c)). Instead, just do `return EXIT_FAILURE` or `return EXIT_SUCCESS` as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your code, and think about the spec:

It should be, put all letters in order in a circle, if the input is in position n, the output is in position n + shift.

What you have is quite a lot more complicated, and in no way meets the spec.

---

1. You should add `tempMsg.reserve(str.size());` to avoid reallocations.
2. You should move the line into `tempMsg` instead of making a spurious copy.
3. Consider normalising the shift before using it. And why not pre-calculate a lookup-table for use in the transform? Your choice on whether to do it on the fly, or do all 26 possible ones at compile-time.
4. There isn't actually any advantage to using `std::transform` instead of a for-range-loop, but anyway the third argument should be `lines.begin()`.
5. Your naming is curious: `str` for all lines, `lines` for a single line... Also, why not call `tempMsg` something Shorter but more descriptive like `ret`?
6. You might want to reconsider your decision to read the whole file into memory before starting processing. It isn't even useful to read it as separate lines instead of blocks.

Comment: Hi, about point 5. You are rigth I forgot to change variables when I went from reading just one string to reading files. Point 6 - do you mean read as I do the encoding? Point 3 - What do you mean by lookup-table? Anyway thank you for your help!

Comment: re 6: Yes, no need for any dynamic allocation. re 3: Simply a `unsigned char[1 + (unsigned char)-1]` where you pre-compute the result for every input, making the transformation itself trivial. And as there are only 26 variations for that lookup-table, it might make sense to calculate them all at compile-time and choose.